# Regular expression for matching latex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to learn regular expressions by writing something akin to latex2html in Python. But I am having a hard time figuring out how to match latex equations -- things of the form $ ... $ where ... can be any expression in LaTeX, while allowing for escape sequences at the same time.

In other words, the problem case is $\$$. I want the regular expression to match on $\$$, rather than just $\$.

Comment: Regular expressions are probably not the best tool for parsing LaTeX.

Comment: You'll probably have better success using a full-blown [parser generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators) to parse LaTeX.

Comment: I am just parsing out equations, and running them through latex/dvips/convert for now, so the theoretical limitations of regex are not yet a problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind to make sure you don't match \$. something like:

```
\\$.*?(?<!\\\\)\\$
```

E.g.

```
print re.findall("\\$.*?(?<!\\\\)\\$", "$x= \$12$ and $x=12$")
```

will find two matches: `$x= \$12$` and `$x=12$`

Comment: This will break if there are \$ in the text outside of the math. In this case you need `r"(?<!\\)\$.*?(?<!\\)\$"`, where I have used raw string [notation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation) to avoid doubling all the `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Petar should get you started.

It might also be helpful to look at an example of some Python code designed to handle LaTeX markup:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bf7329190ca6/Tools/scripts/texcheck.py